# Why my function called multiple times after scanning the barcode through barcode scanner device in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I am working on point of sale application here i am facing an issue when i am scanning barcode through barcode scanner device, my function called multiple times. For example when i am scanning barcode first time my function call one time, when i am scanning barcode without refreshing the page then function called two times,when i am scanning barcode third times then function called 4 times,that means function called multiple of 2. Here is my code which i have done, please check and rectify my issue.

// This is my barcode scanner function, in this function there are two api called 1 for getting whole invoice through barcode which length is more than or equal to 15 and 2 for after scanning barcode to get product.

```
$scope.returnProductByScanner = function (cod) { 
    if($location.path() == "/returnSale"){
        if(cod != undefined){
            var n = cod.length;
            if(n == 15 || n > 15){
                var action = {"barcode": cod};
                var getDt = customerService.viewInvoiceOnBarcode(action);
                getDt.then(function(data){
                    if(data.status == "success"){
                        var so = data.SO;
                        so.return = "return";
                        var sop = data.SOProducts;
                        $scope.addParkedProductIntoBag(sop,so);
                    }else{
                        var msg = data.error;
                        $scope.responseMsg(msg,"Failed");
                    }
                })
            }else{
            // if($scope.newBagListOfProduct.length > 0){
                var action = {"barcode":cod,"userid":uid,"org_id":org_id};
                var getDt = customerService.getBarcodeScannedData(action);
                    getDt.then(function(data){
                        if(data.status == "success"){
                            var prodData = data.product;
                            $scope.addProductInBagSaleReturn(prodData);
                        }else{
                            var msg = data.msg;
                            $scope.responseMsg(msg,"Failed");
                        }
                    })
                // }else{
                //     var msg = "Please first add invoice for return!";
                //     $scope.responseMsg(msg,"Failed");
                // } 
            }
        }
    //$('input[name="myInput"]').focus();
    }else{
        cod = undefined;
    }
    $('input[name="myInput"]').focus();
};
```

// This is my HTML code

```
 <div>     
    <div data-barcode-scanner="returnProductByScanner"></div>
    <div><input  name="myInput" type="text" 
                 data-ng-model="testvalueret"
                 id="t"  autofocus/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

// This is the derective what i have used.

```
 .directive('barcodeScanner', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',    
    scope: {
        callback: '=barcodeScanner',        
      },      
    link:    function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs){       
        // Settings
        var zeroCode = 48;
        var nineCode = 57;
        var enterCode = 13;    
        var minLength = 3;
        var delay = 300; // ms

        // Variables
        var pressed = false; 
        var chars = []; 
        var enterPressedLast = false;

        // Timing
        var startTime = undefined;
        var endTime = undefined;

        jQuery(document).keypress(function(e) {            
            if (chars.length === 0) {
                startTime = new Date().getTime();
            } else {
                endTime = new Date().getTime();
            }

            // Register characters and enter key
            if (e.which >= zeroCode && e.which <= nineCode) {
                chars.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
            }

            enterPressedLast = (e.which === enterCode);

            if (pressed == false) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    if (chars.length >= minLength && enterPressedLast) {
                        var barcode = chars.join('');                                                
                        //console.log('barcode : ' + barcode + ', scan time (ms): ' + (endTime - startTime));

                        if (angular.isFunction(scope.callback)) {
                            scope.$apply(function() {
                                scope.callback(barcode);  
                                alert(barcode);  
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    chars = [];
                    pressed = false;
                },delay);
            }
            pressed = true;
        });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Maybe the keypress is readded everytime the callback is called. Could you try console.log in the  top of the  link function declaration and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives that add event handlers to external elements need to remove those event handlers when the scope is destroyed:

```
app.directive('barcodeScanner', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',    
    scope: {
        callback: '=barcodeScanner',        
      },      
    link:  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs){       

       jQuery(document).on("keypress", keypressHandler);
       scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
           jQuery(document).off("keypress", keypressHandler);       
       });


       function keypressHandler(e) {            
            if (chars.length === 0) {
                startTime = new Date().getTime();
            } else {
                endTime = new Date().getTime();
            }
            //...
       }
    }
  }
})
```

The AngularJS framework builds and destroys elements in the course of its operation. When those elements are destroyed, their respective scope is also destroyed and any necessary cleanup should be performed.